# Netbeans marks as error function of string.h after insert boost libraries

Tags: c++, netbeans, boost

When I include the boost libraries into my project, Netbeans highlights as error the substr() function ("unable to resolve the identifier substr()").
Although this, if I execute the project, the project works correctly.... 
Further the boost libraries also works correctly.
When I try remove the directive for include the boost libraries, the substr error disappears... why???

Comment: Your #includes should be in the order {language, operating system, external libraries, your own}.

Comment: @EJP Or.. your own, language, os, externals. That prevents you from building headers that are dependent on their including source/header files to fulfill your header's dependencies. If you have `std::string` in your header, don't make it the job of the including `.cpp` file to include `<string>` before including your header. It belongs in your header, *and* the .cpp file if *it* directly uses `std::string`. One way to make sure you do it right is to include your headers *first* and don't put `uses namespace ...` in global header-land.